# Batch commands to change IP and DNS

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, netsh

I have written few commands in batch to execute them on choice basis. I am using 2 IP addresses for which I have to change IPv4 and DNS every time I switch between IPs.

I have done this code and this works correctly if I execute line by line but in batch they give errors.

```
@ECHO OFF 
SET /P no= Welcome dude so what are you up to press 1 for buzznet,2 for BSNL :

IF "%NO%"=="1" GOTO BUZZ
IF "%NO%"=="2" GOTO BSNL

:BUZZ
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" source=static ^
      addr=192.168.22.19 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.22.1
netsh interface ip add dns name="Ethernet" addr=192.168.18.1
netsh interface ip add dns name="Ethernet" addr=8.8.8.8 index=2

:BSNL
netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" dhcp
netsh interface ip set dns “Ethernet” dhcp
pause
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: use variables with surrounding `%` (at the beginning and at the end) `%NO` makes no sense, it should be `%NO%`. Remove the `@echo off` to see, which line is generating the errormessage.

Comment: yes sorry & i have uploaded the image link which is output after executed batch

Comment: You need `goto :eof` before both `:BUZZ` and `:BSNL` to not fall into the wrong block of code unintentionally...

Comment: Thanks for the script. This made my day.! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comments you need to add something that stop the script continuing when the job is done. (`goto:EOF` or `exit /b 0`)

```
@ECHO OFF 

:retry
SET /P no= Welcome dude so what are you up to press 1 for buzznet,2 for BSNL :

IF "%no%"=="1" GOTO BUZZ
IF "%no%"=="2" GOTO BSNL
rem if %no% is not 1 nor 2 then exit or goto :retry.
exit /b 0

:BUZZ
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" source=static ^
      addr=192.168.22.19 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.22.1
netsh interface ip add dns name="Ethernet" addr=192.168.18.1
netsh interface ip add dns name="Ethernet" addr=8.8.8.8 index=2
rem job done, then exit with a pause before
pause
exit /b 0

:BSNL
netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" dhcp
netsh interface ip set dns "Ethernet" dhcp
pause
```

Also the last command are malformed with quotes `“Ethernet”` should be `"Ethernet"`

Comment: the label `:retry` should be moved before the `set /p`, otherways you create an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

I checked this before doing a script to change between a static IP and dynamic so I thought of adding my solution in case it´s useful.

- There are two options also to check the status of the network interfaces and to check the current IP.
- Everything for the interface called "Ethernet".
- Because this needs to run as admin, what I did was this: this bat was stored in my folder, C:/workset/scripts/ then I created a shortcut, copied this on the Desktop.
  Then the shortcut, I went to Properties and there I checked the option to Run as admin and also just becase, changed the icon to a cool one.
  So now I can run it from the desktop as any other program and it runs as admin from the start.

  ```
   @ECHO OFF
    cls
    ECHO ________________________________
    ECHO    Only works if run as admin.
    ECHO.
    :MENU
    ECHO.
    ECHO.
    ECHO _______________________________
    ECHO                     MENU
    ECHO ................................
    ECHO Choose an option:
    ECHO.
    ECHO     1 IP static 192.X.X.X, 255.X,X.X
    ECHO     2 IP dynamic
    ECHO     3 Check current IP
    ECHO     4 Check network interfaces status
    ECHO     5 EXIT
    ECHO .................................. 
    ECHO.
    ECHO.

    SET /P M=Write 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 and press ENTER:  
    IF %M%==1 GOTO STATIC
    IF %M%==2 GOTO DYNAMIC
    IF %M%==3 GOTO CHECK
    IF %M%==4 GOTO CHECKIF
    IF %M%==5 GOTO EOF

    :STATIC
    ECHO ______________________________
    ECHO.
    ECHO Changing IP to 192.X.X.X and subred mask to 255.X.X.X
    netsh interface ip set address name= "Ethernet" static 192.X.X.X 255.X.X.X
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO ____________________________
    netsh interface ip show config name="Ethernet"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    GOTO MENU


    :DYNAMIC
    ECHO _______________________________
    ECHO.
    ECHO Changing to a dynamic IP...
    netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" dhcp
    TIMEOUT /T 4 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO _____________________________
    netsh interface ip show config name="Ethernet"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    GOTO MENU

    :CHECK
    ECHO __________________________________
    ECHO Showing the adapter details...
    netsh interface ip show config name="Ethernet"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    GOTO MENU

    :CHECKIF
    ECHO ____________________________________
    ECHO Showing the network interface status....
    netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    GOTO MENU
  ```

There should be an error handling but I dont have time, so this is it.

Another note: tbh, at the end I just removed all the options and created one to change to the static IP and another to the dynamic IP so now I just run them faster.

Comment: Lol bro this question was ages ago. Thanks for help but i don't need it any more

Comment: My reason to add it was that if in the future I´m searching for this again I can find it, or someone else looking for the info. A lot of times I´m looking for something and find solutions in questions made a long time ago so I find very useful when people post their solutions at any time :)